# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'gb' not found

Tags: r, glm

I want to loop through glm with multiple dependent variables.

```
for (y in DV){
 form <- formula(paste(y, "~", IV))
 models_CARD_no0[[y]] <- glm(form, data=CARD_2017_table_no0_log2_glm,) 
              }
```

However, it fails with  `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'gb' not found`

Same is true when I try to run `lme4::glmer()` instead of `glm()`

Comment: IV is the Independent Variable. the formula pastet will be: formula (GeneX ~ stage), where GeneX is a Gene in DV and IV simply is stage

Comment: ok, can you update your post with a small reproducible example so that it can be tested. thanks (preferably with `dput`)

Comment: when I replace IV by "stage", the same error arises

Comment: I tried your code with `mtcars` data and it is working fine though.  I am guessing that one of DV variable names are not matching with the column names of your data

Comment: I uploeaded the reproducable file to :https://seafile.rlp.net/d/e1e2ed7f5157423a8dbf/

The IV variable in CARD_2017_table_no0_log2_glm is in the last column (180)

Comment: If you have column names that are non-standard, please consider to make it standard i.e. you can use `clean_names` from `janitor` before doing this

Comment: ahh ok, yes that might be the reason why it fails. I will give it a shot, many thank!!